# redirecting from stderror seems to stop my gitlab-ci script

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, stderr

I'm having some issues when running a script in my Gitlab CI pipeline.

I'm deploying my services into a Kubernetes cluster, and for this task, I'm trying to see if a particular `PersistentVolumeClaim` exists.

It took a long time to find out that I need to write from `stderr` in case the pvc was not found, just to be able to store that error in a variable. I'm sure there must be better ways to achieve the same thing I'm trying to do so I'm open to those suggestions as well.

```sh
echo "Checking if given pvc it's still around..."
PVC=$(kubectl get pvc $PVC_TO_RESTORE 2>&1)
echo "redirect from stderror is not the problem"
if echo $PVC | grep -q 'Error from server (NotFound): persistentvolumeclaims'; then
  echo "$PVC_TO_RESTORE seems to have been deleted beforehand. Continuing..."
else
  echo "$PVC_TO_RESTORE must be deleted before restoring!"
  exit 1
fi
```

The second `echo` is never printed on console, and my pipeline fails as the following image
[image]

What's going on in here?

Answer (score 0):

> It took a long time to find out that I need to write from stderr in case the pvc was not found

As far as I know, `kubectl` will exit non-zero when it cannot do what you asked, but in your case you want to exit if it *does* exist:

```shell
if kubectl get -o name pvc $PVC_TO_RESTORE; then
  echo "$PVC_TO_RESTORE must be deleted before restoring!"
  exit 1
fi
echo "$PVC_TO_RESTORE seems to have been deleted beforehand. Continuing..."
```

I suspect the redirection is consuming some valuable error message, which is another good reason not to use the "echo | grep" pattern.

You can optionally redirect just stdout if having the name in the CI logs bothers you:

```
if kubectl get -o name ... >/dev/null; then
fi
```